# BadMethodCallException: Method year does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to create a set of tables in my database via migration. So, for one of the tables I have this line among others:

```
$table->year('year')->nullable(false);
...
```

and it seems that there is an issue with this line since I am getting the following error message after typing in `php artisan migrate:fresh` command:

> [BadMethodCallException]
>   Method year does not exist.

No typos on my part, tried a different column name, tried without `nullable(false)`. `YEAR` type is available in my database (10.1.28-MariaDB).
The line in question is just like the others inside the closure creating the table.

I have come across lots of similar topics on the internet but they involve other methods (often custom users' methods, not Laravel built-in ones) and in those cases people tried to call methods in their controllers/models and basically they confused/missed objects which is not the case here. Laravel 5.5.22, localhost, Windows. So, how to fix this issue and make migration create the table?

Comment: You should take a look at the methods available in https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations

Comment: The `migrate:fresh` command will drop all tables from the database and then execute the  migrate command: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations which is what I need since I want to drop all the tables and create a new set. It is on localhost.

Comment: Yep my bad, I `migrate:fresh` is legit

Comment: I found a different syntax for year. Its `integer('year', 4);`. Could you try it?

Comment: yeah...but as I understand it will create an integer column called "year", not a column of type "year" as it is described in the db docs. Sure, it can be a way to go if I get totally stuck.

Comment: You are right about `year`method. But, if you are using Laravel 5.5, maybe it worth updating its version. This method was not present in 5.4.

Comment: As @Laerte suggested i would say try to revert back to exactly v 5.5

Comment: I actually [don't see year listed in the grammar anymore](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.html)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Is it for all 5.5.* or just for the latest current version 5.5.22? I mean doest it make sense to go back to an earlier version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the `year type` isn't listed in the API Docs for 5.5 for the Mysql Grammar Type

[You can view that here](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.html)

However, the github repository shows that it was added [in this commit here](https://github.com/illuminate/database/commit/6effb7bff86d1bd78a9265dabae6dd214e448f70#diff-058ee424cf0316dc9d30a14a37c7ca92)

On [this hash](https://github.com/illuminate/database/commit/f7189adeb09110849ef504e267962c8d0c5c94bb#diff-058ee424cf0316dc9d30a14a37c7ca92) you can see Taylor has fixed some issues with some conflicts concerning the `typeYear` method.

So my conclusion is that you must manually use `illuminate/database` and `5.7-dev`. As the current version listed in `laravel/framework` is `self.version`. which resolves to `5.5-dev` which does not have the `typeYear` method in the `MysqlGrammar`, but `5.7-dev` does.